# how to pass the string in url so that we may get required result in iphone app

Tags: iphone, url, nsstring

I want that this url gives sub catgories i want that if user gives like test so that is id i want to pass through this url so that it should give records containing id 1.

```
test="1";
NSArray *tempArray =[[DataController staticVersion] startParsing:@"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/getSubCategory.php"];
```

Comment: What is your exact problem

Comment: Are you trying to use a url scheme?  So if someone's in safari and clicks a link it opens in the app but carries data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it like this ?

```
NSArray *tempArray =[[DataController staticVersion] startParsing:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/getSubCategory.php?test=%@",test]];
```